# Two Dimentional Multi-Criterion Lookup

Tags: excel, lookup, vlookup

I have a dataset that is structured as follows

```
Metric      Month   Group 1 Group 2 Group 3 Group 4 Group 5 Total
Metric 1    Jan-16  3       2       2       3       3       13
Metric 2    Jan-16  4       345     345     4       4       702
Metric 3    Jan-16  7       7       7       7       7       35
Metric 1    Feb-16  4       89      89      4       4       190
Metric 2    Feb-16  2       9       2       4       17      34
Metric 3    Feb-16  345     3       345     2       3       698
Metric 1    Mar-16  7       4       7       345     4       367
Metric 2    Mar-16  89      7       89      7       7       199
Metric 3    Mar-16  9       4       9       89      4       115
Metric 1    Apr-16  3       7       3       9       7       29
Metric 2    Apr-16  4       7       4       7       89      111
Metric 3    Apr-16  7       7       7       7       9       37
```

I have a dashboard for each metric. Below is an example dashboard for Metric 1. The objective is for the value for each month, group (e.g. Total, Group 1, etc.), and metric to populate the appropriate cell under each month. I assume this would require a multi-criterion lookup function but I'm unsure how to structure it. Thoughts?

```
**Total**                   
          Jan-16    Feb-16  Mar-16  Apr-16  May-16
Metric 1                    

**Group 1**                 
          Jan-16    Feb-16  Mar-16  Apr-16  May-16
Metric 1                    

**Group 2**                 
          Jan-16    Feb-16  Mar-16  Apr-16  May-16
Metric 1
```

Comment: If you are using only Integers you can use a simple `Sumifs(SumRange,CriteriaRange1,Criteria1,CriteriaRange2,Criteria2)`

Comment: Can you use a Sumif function for a  table though, since its across multiple columns?

Comment: If the table is standardised I don't see why not. Take as example: `Sumifs(A4:D4,A2:D2,"Metric 1",A3:D3,"Jan-16")` this will sum the value of row 4 if row 2 has "Metric 1" and row 3 has the correct month. If this approx wont work because of the way the information is outlined (more than 2 dimensions) in the table you'll need to use a combination of LOOKUPS OFFSETS and REFERENCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can certainly be done with a combination of SUMIFS and INDEX/MATCH.

If the data is in A1:H13 and the dashboard starts in J1, the formula is:-

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX($C$2:$H$13,,MATCH($J1,$C$1:$H$1,0)),$B$2:$B$13,K2,$A$2:$A$13,$J3)
```

starting in K3 and copied across and down as required.

The idea is that it will match the Group in the cell two rows above, the Month in the same column and one row above, and the Metric in the same row and to the left.

You could also put in Metric * if you wanted to combine all metrics.

[image]

Comment: Tom - This is perfect! Thanks! Quick question: instead of using $B$2:$B$13, for example, why doesn't the formula work when using $B:$B?

Comment: It will work as long as everything is lined up, so you could use =SUMIFS(INDEX($A:$H,,MATCH($J1,$1:$1,0)),$B:$B,K2,$A:$A,$J3) . I always test things over a small range first to make sure they're OK :-)